# How to append text to JTextArea, among other process that have priority?

Tags: java, swing

Here is little piece of full code:

```
                        textArea.append("Strana " + pos);
                        getUrlSource("www.google.com");
```

I can't get that append to textArea before getUrlSource returns control. How can i append text before that function, like that function get some priority? `getUrlSource` - download `HTML` for particular website. Also tried to set `new Thread`, like this, but no success:

```
public class ProggressBarClass implements Runnable {

    JProgressBar pBar;
    JTextArea txtArea;
    int strana;

    public ProggressBarClass(JProgressBar pBar, JTextArea txtArea, int strana){

        this.pBar = pBar;
        this.txtArea = txtArea;
        this.strana = strana;
    }

    public void (String text){
        txtArea.append(text);
    }

    public void run(){

        pBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        txtArea.append("poceto od: " + strana);

    }

}
```

Also i made function called `apendText` to add text in meanwhile running program, but both doesn't works [ `run`, `appendText` ]. This class called like this, before function `getUrlSource`:

```
ProggressBarClass barClass = new ProggressBarClass(progressBar, textArea, pos);
                    new Thread(barClass).start();
```

Found this text in javadoc:  Swing is not thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

A rough suggestion:

String str1 = textArea.getText() + "Strana " + pos;
textArea.append("Strana " + pos);

while (!textArea.getText().equals(str1)); // wait for text area to get updated

getUrlSource("www.google.com");

Answer (score 0):

I think that Your code is being executed in EDT. Therefore textarea has no chance to repaint itself before You execute the getUrlSource() method and You do not see appended text. I would try following code:

```
 textArea.append("Strana " + pos);
 textArea.repaint()
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
 {
     getUrlSource("www.google.com");
 });
```